# Undetectable shrines in Zelda BotW that are not heroic missions

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm trying to find all shrines in Zelda BotW and I was wondering if there is any shrine that is both unable to be detected by the Sheika sensor and is not a Heroic quest. I'm referring, for instance, to Tho Kayu Shrine, which is not part of any quest but only appears after you kill the Moldora and light four torches.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can still access the Tho Kayu Shrine *without* killing the Molduga that guards it. Makes it more difficult, but still possible

Comment: @Wondercricket yes, you are correct, but I think you still have to light up the torches though

Answer (score 2):

Saas Ko'sah Shrine qualify I think. I'm not aware of any quest for it, although if I remember correcly, there's a character that give a hint about it in a stable.

It is located

> in Hyrule Castle, dock access

and can be found by

> lighting the big brazier on the upper platform.

Comment: But isn't this shrine also detectable by the Sheikah Slate (which is part of the OPs question)?

Comment: Well it's buried (coming out of the ground when you trigger the action put in the spoiler tag) so I guess not, but I cannot check since it would need to start a new game and goes all the way to Hyrule castle.

Comment: The one at the Hebra Great Fossil (and another one with the same principle IIRC) doesn't detect either, until you break open the gate with a large-enough snowball. It technically doesn't have a shrine quest (although the Fossils Sidequest needs-ish it), so I guess it qualifies.

Comment: @EgorHans: That's funny, my recollection is that said shrine *did* set off my Sheikah sensor all the damn time, which was annoying as it took me a completely unreasonable number of attempts to get the door open.

Comment: I did play a new since then and confirm that the shrine doesn't sett the Sheikah Slate sensor off.